# ngFor creates new element, but does not display newly POSTed data until browser refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm new to Angular and am getting an unexpected result from my `*ngFor` directive.

When I click the 'add' button a new `<li>` element is created, but it's `{{ tomato.name }}` data isn't displayed until I refresh the browser:

Screenshots of when I added a 'Test2' input, and after refreshing browser:

**added 'Test2'**

[image]

**after refresh**

[image]

**component.html**

```
<div>
  <label>Tomato name:
    <input #tomatoName />
  </label>
  <button (click)="add(tomatoName.value); tomatoName.value='';">
    add
  </button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let tomato of tomatos">
    <p>{{ tomato.name }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TomatoService } from '../services/tomato.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tomatos',
  templateUrl: './tomatos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tomatos.component.css']
})
export class TomatosComponent implements OnInit {

  tomatos: Tomato[];

  constructor(private tomatoService: TomatoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTomatos();
  }

  getTomatos(): void {
    this.tomatoService.getTomatos()
      .subscribe(tomatos => this.tomatos = tomatos)
  }

  add(name:string): void {
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.tomatoService.addTomato({name} as Tomato)
    .subscribe(tomato => this.tomatos.push(tomato));
  }

}

export interface Tomato {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  originPostCode: string;
  tastes: string;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Tomato } from '../tomatos/tomatos.component';
import { Observable, of } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TomatoService {

  private tomatosUrl = 'https://path/tomy/api'    

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTomatos(): Observable<Tomato[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tomato[]>(this.tomatosUrl);
  }

  addTomato (tomato: Tomato): Observable<Tomato> {
    return this.http.post<Tomato>(this.tomatosUrl, tomato);
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using tomatos:Tomato[];?

Comment: @James Peart for such issues you should provide the plunker for it as you without knowing proper root cause you should not use the solutions which may effect the performance in future.
You should avoid changeDetectorRef unless there is something bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Import [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) from `@angular/core` and manually run change detection after `this.tomatos.push(tomato)` like below:

```
constructor(private tomatoService: TomatoService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTomatos();
  }

  getTomatos(): void {
    this.tomatoService.getTomatos()
      .subscribe(tomatos => {
          this.tomatos = tomatos;
          this.ref.detectChanges(); 
       })
  }

  add(name:string): void {
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.tomatoService.addTomato({name} as Tomato)
    .subscribe(tomato => this.tomatos.push(tomato));
  }
```

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: Beat me to it =) I had to do the same thing for a similar issue.

Comment: I made the change, but am still getting the same result.  For more clarity, here is the error being displayed in my console:  `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]`

Comment: @coder I don't believe that for this simple piece of code angular is really failing to detect the changes. It could be an issue with subscription which he is doing in his component and never unsubscribing it. 
Frankly i don't go with that route. Debugging more could help to find the route cause.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tomato?.name` it will work as this property does not have the value the time it is trying to bind